# Given a substitution S and list Xs, how to apply S to Xs

Tags: variables, prolog, dcg, unification

Suppose I have a substitution *S* and list *Xs*, where each variable occurring in *Xs* also occurs in *S*. How would I find the list *S(Xs)*, i.e., the list obtained by applying the substitution *S* to the list *Xs*.

More concretely, I have a set of predicates and DCG rules that look something like

```
pat(P)   --> seg(_), P, seg(_).
seg(X,Y,Z) :- append(X,Z,Y).
```

If I attempt to match a pattern *P* with variables against a list, I receive a substitution *S*:

```
?- pat([a,X,b,Y],[d,a,c,b,e,d],[]).
   X = c,
   Y = e
```

I want to apply the substitution *S = {X = c, Y = e}* to a list *Xs* with variables *X* and *Y*, and receive the list with substitutions made, but I'm not sure what the best way to approach the problem is.

If I were approaching this problem in Haskell, I would build a finite map from variables to values, then perform the substitution. The equivalent approach would be to produce a list in the DCG rule of pairs of variables and values, then use the map to find the desired list. This is not a suitable approach, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the substitution is not reified (is not a Prolog object), you can bind the list to a variable and let unification do its work:

```
?- Xs = [a,X,b,Y], pat(Xs,[d,a,c,b,e,d],[]).
Xs = [a, c, b, e],
X = c,
Y = e .
```

**Edit**: If you want to keep the original list around after the substitution, use `copy_term`:

```
?- Xs = [a,X,b,Y], copy_term(Xs,Ys), pat(Xs,[d,a,c,b,e,d],[]).
Xs = [a, c, b, e],
X = c,
Y = e,
Ys = [a, _G118, b, _G124] .
```

Comment: I intended *Xs* to be a different list than the DCG rule argument, but this answer was helpful. I wasn't thinking the way prolog wanted me to think, and you helped me restructure my program in accordance with your answer. Thanks.